# Log.v work but unable to debug app in android simulator

Tags: java, android, debugging

I am trying to debug an application but it's not working. Please can someone suggest me what is happening from screenshot I have posted below:

> [image]

@Kumar Bibek thanks for your comment but I am still confused with what you talking about. I know you tell me it's disabled but it's goes hide if I toggle it. it's removed or show as this. Never got without cross.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have disabled all the breakpoints. The breakpoints have a line across it. Go to the Debug window, and re-enable the break points.

Comment: Please rephrase your question so that it can be understood what the problem is.

Comment: @KumarBibek I am unsure. I do click its' happen when  I try to right click toggle its' going removed. I am confused how to get it enabled. Do I have mismatch my setting somewhere.

Comment: @KumarBibek See a new screenshot for clarification.

Comment: @user2243316 Did you check my answer?

Comment: Check the below answer. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window -> Show View -> Other... -> Debug -> Breakpoints

There is a symbol corresponding to the icons on your screenshot (breakpoint with a line through). Click it, and the breakpoints won't be skipped.